# Split string with regex but include part of the regex in the substrings

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
"tag0 tag1 yellow\ green tag2"
```

I want to split it after each space that is not escaped, so I get this result:

```
result[0] = "tag0"
result[1] = "tag1"
result[2] = "yellow\ green"
result[3] = "tag2"
```

Is there any function that can do this for me? The [string.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with the regex `"[^\\] "` removes the last character as well, which I want to avoid. This is what I get with string.split and `"[^\\] "`:

```
result[0] = "tag"
result[1] = "tag"
result[2] = "yellow\ gree"
result[3] = "tag2"
```

Comment: Use negative lookahead but it doesn't guarantee if preceding backslash is not itself an escaped backslash.

Comment: [You may use `(?<!\\)\h+`](https://regex101.com/r/mjIeGH/1) for splitting.

Comment: @anubhava `(?<!(?:\\{2}){0,9999}\\)\h+` assuming backslashes may precede backslashes before a space.

Comment: @ctwheels I don't know why but the pattern you suggested is giving me an error, is there any flag that I am missing?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat are you escaping each backslash?

Comment: @ctwheels No, I just copy pasted the pattern into regex101.com. No modifications.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat it won’t work on regex101, it’s a different regex engine. Copy paste it into your java code and escape each backslash

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah it works :)

Comment: @ctwheels Did you mean `(?<!(?<!\\)(?:\\{2}){0,9999}\\)\h+`?

Comment: @revo yep thanks for the correction, typing that out on my phone wasn’t easy haha

Comment: @ctwheels No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a negative lookbehind could be a work around but it doesn't guarantee if preceding backslash is not itself an escaped backslash. For example:

```
tag0 tag1 yellow\\ green tag2
```

If you can avoid splitting and rather doing a match below regex would match expected chunks:

```
[^\s\\]+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/QWz7bM/1)

Breakdown:

- `[^\s\\]+` Match anything but whitespaces and backslashes
- `(?:` Start non-capturin group

  - `\\.` Match an escape character
  - `[^\s\\]*` Match anything but whitespaces and backslashes
- `)*` End of NCG, repeat as many times as possible

Java:

```
String regex = "[^\\s\\\\]+(?:\\\\.[^\\s\\\\]*)*";
String string = "tag0 tag1 yellow\\ green tag2";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/HkaA7a)